# Send ajax request and got response with prototype.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, prototypejs, response

I try to send to [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/) request with prototype.js

My code:

```
function loadTest() 
{ 
     new Ajax.Request('http://httpbin.org/get', { method:'get',
        // success request
        onSuccess: 
            function(transport) {
                alert("Success! \n\n" + transport.status);
        },
        // fail request
        onFailure: 
            function() { 
                alert('Something went wrong...'); 
            }
     });
}
```

After execution i got: `Success!` and `transport.status = 0`

Why? How can i correctly send request and get response with prototype.js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code, except for one thing, You cannot make cross-domain `XMLHttpRequest`.

You should use a proxy that enables [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/).

Another option is [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) request.

As I see both of them is not available for [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/).